# Maven: Where to find default bindings of package?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Wanted to know where default packaging and plugins bindings mentioned in Maven package. Maven official [document](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html) says, it is available in `META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml` But, I coundn't find the default-bindings.xml.

I found one of JAR file named `plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar` from 'apache-maven-3.5.3/boot' path, extracted but couldn't found default bindings information there also.

Please help me to find default bindings information and usage of plexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default-binding.xml file is part of the maven-core jar, [here the github repo](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml)

On your disk the path is : ${MAVEN_HOME}/lib/maven-core-x.y.z/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml

Comment: It is also defined in each packaging plugin like maven-jar-plugin see here: https://github.com/apache/maven-jar-plugin/blob/master/src/main/filtered-resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml The rational behind that is to get sometime rid of the packaging definition in maven-core....